# ng-model value from scope array + reference the ng-model name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope variable which looks like this:

```
$scope.lists = [
      {
          name: 'users_selectall'
      },
      {
          name: 'general_selectall'
      }
];
```

I want a dynamic ng-model which its value will be one of the names from the lists array.

I tried reference to my scope variable as specified in other posts:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelNamex"/>
```

But then when I'm referencing "users_selectall" in my controller it doesn't affect the input. For example if I set $scope.users_selectall = false the input doesn't change.

On the other hand if used the model name explicitly, i.e if I wrote the following line:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="users_selectall"/>
```

It would work fine.

How can I set my ng-model to a scope value and reference to this scope name on my controller?

Comment: can you be more clear or maybe create a fiddle or some other working code?

Comment: $scope.users_selectall is a boolean scope variable and I want my input value to be determined by this scope variable value. I want to create these inputs in ng-repeat and to give each one of them a different boolean scope variable (for the first input I want the ng-model to be "users_selectall" and for the next one "general_selectall" and so on). Therefore I want to hold an array of scope variables names (users_selectall, general_selectall) which are set to true/false in different function in the code and to generate each input with its corresponding scope variable name.

Comment: so when the scope variable with the scope variable name is changed the input with the same scope variable name will be changed too.